Why would elves care what happens to Middle Earth?
During the events of Lord of the Rings, some elves like Elrond and Glorfindel clearly cared about what happens to Middle Earth, since they tried to help Frodo get the ring to Mount Doom.
Considering that they'll all have to leave Middle Earth for Valinor eventually, why do they care if Sauron conquers Middle Earth? Presumably they might feel the same way as a terminally ill person thinking about climate change: yes, it's a problem, but it's not their problem, since they're leaving soon anyway.
Curiously Gandalf expresses the same sentiment at the end of the Third Age (when he said the problems of the Fourth Age are not his concern). Gandalf necessarily had to care about Sauron since that's his mission, but presumably the elves didn't.


They are directly concerned as long as they remain in middle earth
Hatred for Sauron and what he represents : the reason some of these elves are here in the first place, historically, is to get revenge from Morgoth. Their hatred might still include his work and his servant Sauron.
Mostly, Idealism / Basic altruism towards their friends and allies : why do expatriates vote ? Why do real people join wars that do not concern them directly (think how WW1 and WW2 started, or volunteers in the spanish civil war, in syria/irak against isis, in ukraine...) ?


Surely the whole reason that they have remained in Middle-Earth in the first place is that they love it. They could all (except for Galadriel) have left for Valinor at any point; they choose not to.

It’s not clear to me that they would be leaving if Sauron had regained the ring. Assuming Sauron conquered middle earth, wouldn’t he enslave the elves and prevent them from leaving? Assuming any elves survive being conquered in the first place.

From a certain point of view, all humans are 'terminally ill' - no one alive now will live beyond 120, probably - and yet some appear to care about climate change. Do you find this surprising?

@AakashM when they have years left to live, no.

@ToddWilcox they could die and be re-embodied, no?

Why do good people care about anything?

@Allure Uhhh, I’m not aware of that possibility being mentioned in the main text of LoTR or the Hobbit. I’ve only read the Silmarillion a couple times and don’t remember any elf dying and being re-embodied, but I might have just forgotten.

@ToddWilcox there's Glorfindel, who died during the First Age and was re-embodied.

@Allure Yeah I either forgot that or haven’t read it, but looking at online sources about it seems like a one-time thing, not something open to all elves all the time. In any case, it doesn’t seem definite that Tolkien intended even glorfindel to be resurrected (the simlarillion was published posthumously) so I don’t think the concept will lead to meaningful answers to this question.

@ToddWilcox according to https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Elven_life_cycle#Death_and_reincarnation, not being re-embodied is the exception, not the norm.

If you want to consider every letter and commentary that Tolkien ever wrote about middle earth to be canon then you’ll be able to reason in circles about a large number of topics. You probably won’t get satisfying answers to a number of questions because he changed his mind and mused openly and had no need to make every word he wrote about his stories consistent or logical. Also check chepner’s answer: at least Elrond thought the elves would be trapped in middle earth if Sauron conquered it.

I expect that any MVGA elves have already left.

Because they have empathy.

All the humans in Middle Earth are going to eventually die anyway, so why should they care what happens to Middle Earth?

@RBarryYoung stuff might happen to Middle Earth before they die.

Let's not forget that the Elves (specifically the Noldor) cooperated with Sauron and created the Rings of Power in the first place. Thus they bear some moral responsibility to try and clean up the mess. (Though admittedly they did a lot to that end in the 2nd Age. Sauron just doesn't die)

First they came for the hobbits...

Galadriel says why. It is not for selfish reasons, but it's not quite altruistic either.
From The Fellowship of the Ring, Book II, Chapter 7, "The Mirror of Galadriel:"

[Galadriel] ... Do you not see now wherefore your coming is to us as
the footstep of Doom? For if you fail, then we are laid bare to the
Enemy. Yet if you succeed, then our power is diminished, and
Lothlorien will fade, and the tides of Time will sweep it away. We
must depart into the West, or dwindle to a rustic folk of dell and
cave, slowly to forget and to be forgotten.’
Frodo bent his head. ‘And what do you wish?’ he said at last.
‘That what should be shall be,’ she answered. ‘The love of the Elves
for their land and their works is deeper than the deeps of the Sea,
and their regret is undying and cannot ever wholly be assuaged. Yet
they will cast all away rather than submit to Sauron: for they know
him now. For the fate of Lothlorien you are not answerable, but only
for the doing of your own task. Yet I could wish, were it of any
avail, that the One Ring had never been wrought, or had remained for
ever lost.'


Can you explain why the highlighted text answers the question? I'm not seeing the connection.

@Allure - Galadriel is saying it isn't for any boon for themselves the Elves care. It's because of Arda Marred, and here's one way to mitigate the marring. If that doesn't help please ask again.

@Allure - I highlighted an additional set of words. Maybe that will clarify my meaning.

@Allure it might help if you edit your question and explain why you find any of this strange. I mean, it would be a tiny bit sociopathic for someone not to care about the world just because they, personally, had the option of leaving it. I'm sure some people are indeed that way, but they will be the aberrations, not the norm.

@terdon there's already a comment to that effect in the question. Have you known any terminally ill people?

Yes there is, but you don't seem to have clarified. And yes, I have known terminally ill people and very old people, but none who were quite so selfish as to not care about the world they were leaving behind. Both because they care, intrinsically (it is hard to stop caring about something when you've spent a lifetime caring) and because they were leaving loved ones behind and cared about their future.

@terdon the latter does not apply in the case of Elves, and the former did not apply to Gandalf (or all the elves who left earlier).

Sorry, @Allure, no idea which former/latter pairing you're targeting there. In any case, it would really help if you could explain in the question because what you describe is how I would expect any healthy person to feel and not caring about a place/person just because you aren't personally affected by their fate is not the behavior I would expect from a "normal" person.

@terdon because they were leaving loved ones behind and cared about their future This is the latter reason, and it is hard to stop caring about something when you've spent a lifetime caring this is the former reason. If you believe this is not already addressed in the OP, feel free to edit it in.

Sorry, @Allure, I don't know what to add since the question reads to me as a paraphrased version of "why aren't the elves heartless sociopaths?". Of course the elves were leaving loved ones behind (be they non-elven friends and acquaintances or middle earth itself) and I have no idea why Gandalf is relevant or why you would think he hadn't spent (several) lifetimes caring. If you feel it's clear, fair enough, I don't really have anything else to add.

It's actually even less altruistic than you think.  She's saying "Given that the One Ring has been found we're screwed either way, but we're more screwed if Sauron gets it, so of course I hope you succeed" But then also basically says "Better that the ring was lost forever or never made". So she's OK with the pre-Hobbit status quo of the Ring lost but Sauron around.  Because with the Ring lost the Elves still get to wield the Three and keep their realms.

Why does anyone care about anything, if they're going to die eventually?
Why does Grandma care about keeping her apartment clean and her children safe?
Life just isn't that simple; people care.
Added to that, Elves are inherently good beings and therefore, it is in their nature to pursue good.
They care for the land they have lived in for so long, for the trees that grow there, and presumably also for the people they've met.
Moreover, they don't know how long they will remain in Middle-earth before sailing to Valinor. They probably don't want to spend the rest of their time in Sauron's kingdom. Not to mention that it could possibly prevent them from leaving if the elven realm falls under his control.

Grandma cares because the historic grandmas that didn't care had fewer surviving grandchildren - natural selection by survival of the fittest. If Elves "evolve" or not (and at what speed) is debatable.
On the other hand, that Elves are intrinsically Good and therefore do Good Things seems like a solid reason to me.

I would disagree that Elves are "inherently" good, something of which we have counterexamples in The Silmarillion. One could say the Ainur were "inherently" good and yet -- Melkor!

You say

Considering that they'll all have to leave Middle Earth for Valinor eventually, why do they care if Sauron conquers Middle Earth?

Galdor says at the Council of Elrond:

Only the waning might of Gondor stands now between [Sauron] and a march in power along the coasts into the North; and if he comes, assailing the White Towers and the Havens, hearafter the Elves may have no escape from the lengthening shadows of Middle-Earth.

If Sauron wins, there will be nowhere to sail from, effectively trapping Elves in Middle-Earth unless they are physically killed.
Elrond adds a moment later

The westward road [i.e., sending the Ring to Valinor] seems easiest. Therefore it must be shunned. It will be watched. Too often the Elves have fled that way.

This implies that it's already too late to sail away: any ships sailing west would likely be easily intercepted by Sauron's naval forces, and any ship thus intercepted isn't likely going to be allowed on its merry way simply because the Ring isn't found on board. The ship will be returned to port for a thorough search, and all hands on board will be captured for interrogation or killed.

There was a level of conscience about the future, expressed here by Gandalf, but no doubt shared by Elrond and Galadriel. Glorfindel may arguably have been asking a Dorothy Dixer:

‘Then,’ said Glorfindel, ‘let us cast it into the deeps, and so make
the lies of Saruman come true. For it is clear now that even at the
Council his feet were already on a crooked path. He knew that the
Ring was not lost for ever, but wished us to think so; for he began
to lust for it for himself. Yet oft in lies truth is hidden: in the Sea it
would be safe.’
‘Not safe for ever,’ said Gandalf. ‘There are many things in the
deep waters; and seas and lands may change. And it is not our part
here to take thought only for a season, or for a few lives of Men, or
for a passing age of the world. We should seek a final end of this
menace, even if we do not hope to make one.’

—The Council of Elrond, Book 2, Lord of the Rings

There have been three good answers (Lesser son, TGar, Machavity) which cover most of the ground, but I'd like to expand on one point: Gandalf's apparent disinterest in the problems of the 4th Age.
The Istari were sent to M-E to guide the people of M-E, but not to rule:

For which reason the Valar are to these kindreds [Men and Elves] rather their elders and their chieftains than their masters; and if ever in their dealings with Elves and Men the Ainur have endeavoured to force them when they would not be guided, seldom has this turned to good, howsoever good the intent.

So, the Istari

...came out of the Far West and were messengers sent to contest the power of Sauron, and to unite all those who had the will to resist him; but they were forbidden to match his power with power, or to seek to dominate Elves or Men by force and fear.

They had one specific task: To contest the power of Sauron, but only by inspiring Elves and Men, not by ruling them.
The fall of Sauron would not only mark the end of a great evil, but also the ending of Elves as a significant presence in M-E. All through the Third Age

Elves, who seldom walked in the Shire, could now be seen passing westward through the woods in the evening, passing and not returning; but they were leaving Middle-earth and were no longer concerned with its troubles.

It was part of the vision of the world seen by the Ainur before Arda was created, that eventually

...the Elves should pass into the twilight and the Dominion of Men begin.

Yet what happened during the Dominion of Men may not have been part of any vision:

And some have said that the vision ceased ere the fulfilment of the Dominion of Men and the fading of the Firstborn; wherefore, though the Music is over all, the Valar have not seen as with sight the Later Ages or the ending of the World.

It was evidently Eru Iluvatar's design to, finally, leave all Arda in the hands of Men, and He didn't even tell the Ainur his plans!  It was none of their business. All the more reason for the Valar to avoid meddling directly!
Gandalf (all the Istari) were embodied and this embodiment limited them and muddied their memories of Aman and of the vision they had seen before the creation of the world. (Though what memories remained may be the source of Gandalf's amazing hunches about Gollum and Bilbo and Hobbits in general.)
Gandalf spent two millennia as a mortal, an old man (unnaturally vigorous, but still subject to the weariness of the body), limited in his power, limited to using only persuasion, restrained from taking leadership -- and yet responsible for the defeat of the most powerful being on M-E, a being who had no compunction about using domination.

'The Third Age was my age. I was the Enemy of Sauron; and my work is finished. I shall go soon. The burden must lie now upon you and your kindred.'

Gandalf was ready -- more than ready -- to return home and to regain his full being. He was ready, his appointed task was successfully completed and Eru Iluvatar Himself had decreed that Men were to be on their own in the Fourth Age.
All of Gandalf's motivations were aligned. It was time to leave.

You include six quotes. May we know what you're quoting in each case, please? I attempted to direct this comment to you with @, but the software didn't fill in your user name, and seems to have removed what I included, so if you don't see this right away I apologize, but it wasn't for want of trying.

@Lesser son They're all from LotR or the Silmarillion.  (And not to worry -- the writer of an answer seems to be automatically notified of comments.)  I'm not sure how to do better, since there's no standard edition to which to refer chanter and verse, and I suspect that including descriptive details in the narrative (e.g., "At the Council of Elrond, Glorfindel said...") would make the main point harder to follow [citation needed].

At Mark Olson (it still isn't working for me) - Published title, book number if from LotR, and chapter, or section in the Sil, are helpful. That's good enough given the plethora of published editions. Page numbers are, of course, in this context meaningless. Here's an arbitrarily-chosen example: in The Hobbit, Chapter 7, "Queer Lodgings," Beorn calls Bilbo [quote bars] Little bunny. [end quote bars]


Elrond and Galadriel still live in Middle Earth. It's harder to ignore what's going on around you.
Sauron never really stopped being an elf problem. They had come to Middle Earth to stop Morgoth (First Age) and then Sauron (Second Age).
It's entirely plausible Galadriel sensed the return of Sauron before anyone else. Tolkien had her be suspicious of Sauron in his Annatar version long before he betrayed everyone in the war of the Second Age. The Hobbit has a necromancer in Dol Guldur, which was Sauron. The Rings of Power (non-Tolkien) depicts Galadriel as driven to find Sauron in the Second Age (not an implausible take on the character). Galadriel would be less likely to leave if she knew Sauron might still be out there.

